# Where do I find the default MVC templates for Html.EditorFor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement my own Html.EditorFor by creating a template in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates.

I would like to start with the vanilla template and change this to my needs.

But where can I see the default editor-for templates of ASP.net MVC?

What I try to do: get my own css classes (uikit instead of bootstrap) and a more simple way of adding validation with jquery.validate (using required attribute, for example).

Comment: Not clear why you think you need to start with the `vanilla` templates (you don't change them). Are you wanting templates for simple types (`string`, `int`, `bool` etc) or to create templates for complex objects (i.e. based your classes)

Comment: I will start with the template for string. If I understand correctly, I would override the default template and thus lose some of its functionality, won't I? Also, to learn how the (more complex) vanilla editors look like would be a great help ...

Comment: To create one for `string`, you just name it `string.cshtml` and then add the markup you want - for example you could generate the label, textbox and validation message placeholder for a string property using `@Html.LabelFor(m => m) @Html.TexBoxFor(m => m) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)` (although I not recommending you do that)

Comment: Its also unclear what you mean by `more simple way of adding validation with jquery.validate` The htmlhelper methods do this out of the box - you just need `EditorFor()` or `TextboxFor()` etc. and the `data-val-*` attributes necessary for client side validation will be added to your html. What could possibly simpler? And the existing methods have the ability to add class names (and other html attributes) so it not clear what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I tried a lot around and I figured out that I was thinking a bit to complicated! Coming from web forms, I never expected to achieve this so easily. MVC is great!

Comment: BUT, although this is indeed not blocking my work, I would find it very interesting to see how Microsoft implemented the original templates!! Would be great if anybody could ANSWER MY QUESTION still!!

Comment: By templates, I assume you mean the code for the `HtmlHelper` methods. You can view (and download) the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)